# Magento 2 Cms block collection

Tags: magento2, collection, static-block

What code would be required to get a complete list of cms blocks in Magento 2. What I mean is block collection like in Magento 1

I would try to keep to repository interfaces like this following:

```
$objectManager->get(\Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface::class)
```

But I would need to also have `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface` passed and it starts to become over the top for just getting the block collection.

What is best and correct method for this simple job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

below is the one of way

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $blockColFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory $blockColFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->blockColFactory = $blockColFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getBlockCOl()
    {
        $data = $this->blockColFactory->create();

        return $data;

    }
}
```